# Copy & Paste column between workbooks with * file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to copy and paste column H from the file that begins with "Dataset" into "Monthly Reporting" (the macro-enabled file I'm using). I'm seeing a 'Subscript out of range' error on the Set SourceColumn line.

```
Sub CAPTest()

Dim file As String
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

file = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\01. January 2021\Dataset*"

Workbooks.Open file

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks(file).Worksheets(1).Columns("H")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Monthly Reporting.xlsm").Worksheets("SampleDoc").Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks` doesn't support wildcards. You need to loop and test each workbook's name. Also there's no way that `Workbooks.Open file` actually works. Better practice would be to use `Dir` with a wildcard to get the actual file name, then use a workbook reference: `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)`. Then you don't have to continually refer to a workbook by name.

Comment: `Workbooks("Monthly Reporting.xlsm")` --> `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Cheers for this BigBen